# Get signer for Blockchain API without private Key

Tags: api, ethsigner

I have a ERC-20 token and I have a smart contract to but and sell the tokens . I have also created frontend and API for this. In the frontend I get signer from the wallet but to do it in the backend I need the user's private key . I want to know is there a way to do it in the API without getting the private key.

frontend: function to buy token.

```
const handleBuyToken = async () => {
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    await window.ethereum.enable();

    const tokenSwapcontract = new ethers.Contract(
      contractAddress,
      TokenSwapABI.abi,
      signer
    );

    const tokenAddress = tokenAddress;
    const token = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, TokenAbi.abi, signer);
    if (numberOfTokens == "" || numberOfTokens == undefined) {
      setErrorMessage("Please enter the number of Tokens.");
    } else {
      const numberOfTokensinNum = Number(numberOfTokens);
      console.log("numberOfTokensinNum", numberOfTokensinNum);
      const numberOftokensinWei = ethers.utils.parseEther(
        String(numberOfTokens)
      );
      console.log("numberOfTokensinNum", String(numberOftokensinWei));
      const ttl = tokenPrice + tokenPrice * (feePercent / 100);
      console.log(ttl);
      const totalAmount = numberOfTokensinNum * ttl;
      console.log("totalAmount", totalAmount);
      const totalAmountinWei = ethers.utils.parseEther(String(totalAmount));

      try {
        const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();

        const tx = await tokenSwapcontract.buyTokens(numberOftokensinWei, {
          value: totalAmountinWei,
          gasLimit: 5000000,
        });

        await tx.wait();
        setSuccessMessage("Transaction successful!");
        window.location.reload(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setErrorMessage("Transaction failed. Please try again.");
      }
    }
  };
```

API :

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import {
  createAeroSwapInstance,
  provider,
} from "../../../helpers/contractInstance/aeroSwapInstance";
import { aeroSwapAddress } from "../../../config";
//import cors from "cors";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    //Check if data is present
    const numberOfTokens = req.body.numberOfTokens;
    const privateKey= req.body.privateKey;

    if (
      numberOfTokens === undefined ||
      numberOfTokens === "" ||
      numberOfTokens === 0
    ) {
      res
        .status(400)
        .json({ success: false, msg: "Number of tokens is required." });
      return;
    }

    const feePercent = 3.65;
    const tokenPrice = 0.0168;

    //Calculating total fee amount to pay
    const numberOfTokensinNum = Number(numberOfTokens);
    const numberOftokensinWei = ethers.utils.parseEther(String(numberOfTokens));
    const pricePerToken = tokenPrice + tokenPrice * (feePercent / 100);
    const totalAmount = numberOfTokensinNum * pricePerToken;
    const totalAmountinWei = ethers.utils.parseEther(String(totalAmount));

    //Set up contract instance
    const aeroSwapInstance = await createAeroSwapInstance(privateKey);
    //Buy tokens
    try {
      const tx = await aeroSwapInstance.functions.buyTokens(
        numberOftokensinWei,
        {
          value: totalAmountinWei,
          gasLimit: 5000000,
        }
      );
      await tx.wait();
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, msg: "Transaction Successful." });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        msg: "Transaction Failed. Please try again.",
      });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, msg: "Bad request." });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't do it with approval?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are on a local network like [ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache), [hardhat node](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/overview) or [foundry's `anvil`](https://book.getfoundry.sh/anvil/), you will need to have a private key in order to sign transactions from an account.

One alternative is to have the user pre-`approve` the amount of token, and then do the transfer on their behalf from one of your accounts, but this will still require signing in the backend.

Finally, you could use something like [amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-sign-ethereum-eip-1559-transactions-using-aws-kms/) [KMS](https://luhenning.medium.com/the-dark-side-of-the-elliptic-curve-signing-ethereum-transactions-with-aws-kms-in-javascript-83610d9a6f81) to do the signing. This is a bit more to implement and has its own security considerations, but you would not need to store the private keys on the backend in this case.

Comment: ok. I need another clarification. In the front end I can prompt metamask for approving the transaction. Is it possible to do it in an API?

Comment: I got this requirement from the client. They want the API to work just like the front end .